# Remove rows with columns having values between -1 and 1 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
   V1         T1         T2         T3         T4        T5
  CXCL6  0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042  5.5800459 5.8477150
  PPBP  0.7739450  0.3587961  0.5073359  0.2743522 0.6221722
  CXCL10  0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387  3.5604672 0.1971432
  CXCL11 -0.2563139  0.7117200  0.0000000 -0.2288303 0.9955557
  CXCL12  0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760  1.2752787 1.2284810
```

I want to remove the rows that have values only between -1 and 1.

I have tried this command but unfortunately it does not work.

```
condition1 <- Genes[,c(2:6)] >=-1 & Genes[,c(2:6)] <=1
Genes <- Genes[condition1,]
```

Can someone tell me where I am wrong so that I can successfully filter my dataframe.

Comment: Try `condition1 <- all(Genes[,c(2:6)] >=-1 & Genes[,c(2:6)] <=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's fast way with base R -

```
Genes[rowSums(abs(Genes[, -1]) > 1) > 0, ]

      V1        T1         T2         T3       T4        T5
1  CXCL6 0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042 5.580046 5.8477150
3 CXCL10 0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387 3.560467 0.1971432
5 CXCL12 0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760 1.275279 1.2284810
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `all` in `apply` to subset *Genes* and *remove rows with columns having all values between -1 and 1*.

```
Genes[!apply(Genes[-1] >= -1 & Genes[-1] <= 1, 1, all),]
#      V1        T1         T2         T3       T4        T5
#1  CXCL6 0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042 5.580046 5.8477150
#3 CXCL10 0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387 3.560467 0.1971432
#5 CXCL12 0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760 1.275279 1.2284810
```

or using `any`:

```
Genes[apply(Genes[-1] < -1 | Genes[-1] > 1, 1, any),]
```

or using `rowSums`:

```
Genes[rowSums(Genes[-1] < -1 | Genes[-1] > 1) > 0,]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use dplyr:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter_at(vars(T1:T5), ~ !dplyr::between(., -1, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

Genes %>%
  filter_if(is.numeric, any_vars(abs(.) > 1))
```

---

```
      V1        T1         T2         T3       T4        T5
1  CXCL6 0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042 5.580046 5.8477150
2 CXCL10 0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387 3.560467 0.1971432
3 CXCL12 0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760 1.275279 1.2284810
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table`-approach

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
library(matrixStats)
DT <- fread("V1         T1         T2         T3         T4        T5
CXCL6  0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042  5.5800459 5.8477150
PPBP  0.7739450  0.3587961  0.5073359  0.2743522 0.6221722
CXCL10  0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387  3.5604672 0.1971432
CXCL11 -0.2563139  0.7117200  0.0000000 -0.2288303 0.9955557
CXCL12  0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760  1.2752787 1.2284810")
```

**code**

```
DT[ !DT[, rowMins( as.matrix(.SD)) > -1 & rowMaxs(as.matrix(.SD)) < 1, 
    .SDcols = patterns("^T")], ]
```

**output**

```
       V1        T1         T2         T3       T4        T5
1:  CXCL6 0.8536601  1.0903336  3.7633042 5.580046 5.8477150
2: CXCL10 0.1258370 -0.3535165 -0.7460387 3.560467 0.1971432
3: CXCL12 0.6181279  1.7529310  1.7637760 1.275279 1.2284810
```